# How do you remind a HR/CEO that you sent them an email without seeming desperate/bad mannered?

Tags: professionalism, internship, email

I have applied at a company for an internship this summer. They replied enthusiastically 2-3 days later asking for more details. I sent them a brief description of my projects, my CV and my interest in the company. It has been a month and still no reply back. Despite this, the person who replied my email the first time turned out to be a friend's teacher in my home country. I told him to ask about internship possibilities in a subtle way and from what he told me they were interested in me and this confused me because I didn't get any reply.

I could get his number from my friend and call him to ask in a more personal way but I feel this lacks lots of professionalism. 
Would something among the lines of "*Hello! Do you happen to have any news regarding this summer's internship? Best regards, x*" be ok?

I want to leave a good impression but I'm not sure what would be suitable without seeming desperate nor cocky.

Comment: What ever you do, do not call them ... mail is fine, go with mail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly follow up. Make sure that it's in a positive manner and highlight the fact that you're excited about working for this company, not that you're simply chasing them up.

Something like

> I'm really looking forward to /excited about the opportunity of working with you.  I know that things looked hopeful the last time we spoke/emailed - is there any good news for me?

Showing people who much you want this (in a positive way) should leave a better feeling than simply another chase-up email.

Comment: "chase-up" email vs. a follow-up, nice.  Great description, I'm going to have to borrow that one!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced professional, but in my personal experience, industry standard and basic email etiquette is to wait for 1 week before sending a follow up message (unless you were specifically asked to wait) or the person is on vacation (auto-reply by vacation responder).

If someone don't reply in a week, it usually mean they missed your E-Mail, or they were going to reply you, but forgot about it later.

It happens with me too and sometime I miss other people E-Mail too. A reminder always helps.

I don't use very fancy message. Even a simple message `Dear x, Did you missed my previous E-Mail?` will suffice. You are always welcome to use that message to show your excitement about joining the company and make it more nicer.

Important Note: In my opinion, waiting for 1 month can backfire you too. If someone send me a follow up E-Mail after 1 month, I will think they are having trouble finding a job, and have not still found a job. That's why they are reaching again after so long. Maybe he is bit desperate for a job.